# Handling multiple UIComponent with Single Skin Class

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, skinning

I have created a simple mxml file with code as follows:

```
<s:application..........>
   <s:BorderContainer>
      <s:SkinnableContainer id="firstRow"/>
      <s:SkinnableContainer id="secondRow"/>
      <s:SkinnableContainer id="thirdRow"/>
   </s:BorderContainer>
</s:application>
```

Now I want to apply different font size, font color and font type and background color on each row i.e each of the three skinnableContainers.Currently I have defined 3 different skin classes for each of row but I think this is a bad programing.
I should create a single skin class for outermost container i.e BorderContainer and any how provide different fonts and background color to all the 3 child containers through that skin class.
So, is it possible that I can create single skin class that can provide different decorations to each of the child container.

Answer (score 4):

You should use styles. [Here is](http://seanhess.net/use-css-to-style-a-custom-spark-skin-in-flex) the sample of it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have gone through your link and I found that it is mainly speaking about decorating a single container and more emphasis was given on using css with skin. But my problem is to decorate different containers with different font, background colors etc with the help of single Skin class.

Comment: You can apply different styles to different container instances with single skin. Isn't it exactly what you've asked?

Comment: I can use this idea. If you have some time, can you give me some rough coding idea about it.

Comment: @jitendra, we are not here to do all the work for you.  Constantiner gave you the information that you need.  It's up to you to do your research and try things out for yourself.  You should also accept his answer.

Comment: @Jitendra Do you still have any problems with implementation?